# AddressSanitizer interceptor_via_fun

Tags: c++, gcc, address-sanitizer

Would like to suppress the following error detected by AddressSanitizer.

```
==114064==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-use-after-scope on address 0x7ffe60fee2f0 at pc 0x000001e6ef34 bp 0x7ffe60feb6c0 sp 0x7ffe60feb6b8
WRITE of size 8 at 0x7ffe60fee2f0 thread T0
    #0 0x1e6ef33 in std::_Function_base::_Function_base() /opt/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/std_function.h:252
    #1 0x1e6ef33 in function<Engine::Engine(const Resource&, SourceDataVersion, Engine::CalculationResolution)::<lambda(std::unique_ptr<const model::Car>)> > /opt/gcc-8.2.0/include/c++/8.2.0/bits/std_function.h:668
    ...
```

I was thinking setting ASAN_OPTIONS=suppressions=asan_blacklist.txt, with asan_blacklist.txt containing

```
interceptor_via_fun:_Function_base
```

would do the trick, as the [documentation](http://releases.llvm.org/3.7.0/tools/clang/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#issue-suppression) says

```
interceptor_via_fun:NameOfCFunctionToSuppress
```

but it doesn't. Was quite shocked to see that googling "AddressSanitizer interceptor_via_fun" returned only 151 results. :/

**What should I put in my suppression file?**

Comment: And now you'll see only your question.

Comment: The OP opened a github issue: https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1027 . Come and vote it up

Comment: Did you tried use mangled name of this `std::_Function_base::_Function_base()` function?

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/google/sanitizers/issues/1027#issuecomment-1147125536 has an explanation.  Also, you're using a lambda and functor here, which may not be supported

Answer (score -3):

Didn't you try this [llvm](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html#suppressing-reports-in-external-libraries) manual?

And add following line to suppress your external library

> interceptor_via_lib:NameOfTheLibraryToSuppress